# Definição de props em função de renderização do Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

O `Vue.js` possui `funções de renderização` e várias formas de definir onde o componente será renderizado, como o uso de `el`, `template` e a função `render`. A função render possui prioridade sobre todas as outras, pela documentação o primeiro parâmetro que a função `render` recebe é `createElement`, sei um pouco de `Javascript` e consigo entender o funcionamento dessa função, mas digamos que queira fazer o seguinte(exemplo hipotético):

```
const spanCustom = {
  functional: true,
  render(h) {
    return h('span', {
      props: {
        show: // Não sei o que colocar aqui para fazer o binding da prop vinda pai
      }
    }, 'See me')
  }
};

const vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    show: false
  }
}).$mount('#app');

<div id="app">
  <span-custom v-if="show"></span-custom>
</div>
```

Minha dúvida é como posso definir `props` na função render nesse caso por exemplo?

Comment: Podes juntar o template que tens para perceber onde está o `spanCustom`?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o show via `v-bind:show` para o componente...

```js
const spanCustom = {
    props: ['show'],
    template: '\
    <span v-if="show">\
      See me\
    </span>'
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true //controlador
  },
  components: {
    'span-custom': spanCustom
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span-custom v-bind:show="show"></span-custom>
</div>
```